# Merging SQL data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This seems so simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have two data sets:

```
SET1
DATE       | TOTAL1 | TOTAL2 | TOTAL3
1 Jun 2013 | 0      | 0      | 5
2 Jun 2013 | 0      | 0      | 12
3 Jun 2013 | 0      | 0      | 34
4 Jun 2013 | 0      | 0      | 50

SET2
DATE       | TOTAL1 | TOTAL2 | TOTAL3
1 Jun 2013 | 1      | 2      | 0
2 Jun 2013 | 4      | 12     | 0
3 Jun 2013 | 5      | 12     | 0
4 Jun 2013 | 6      | 10     | 0
```

I want to create a third dataset the merges these two sets into the following:

```
SET3
DATE       | TOTAL1 | TOTAL2 | TOTAL3
1 Jun 2013 | 1      | 2      | 5
2 Jun 2013 | 4      | 12     | 12
3 Jun 2013 | 5      | 12     | 34
4 Jun 2013 | 6      | 10     | 50
```

Joining the tables does not work. I need to join them in a way that will add the totals if the dates match up. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: It's unclear why you can't just join on `date`. It's also unclear why your columns are named `total`. I can't see the SQL you have tried (even if it does not work), nor the Postgres version you are working with ... Please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
     DATE,
     SUM(TOTAL1) AS TOTAL1,
     SUM(TOTAL2) AS TOTAL2,
     SUM(TOTAL3) AS TOTAL3
FROM
(
     SELECT
          DATE,
          TOTAL1,
          TOTAL2,
          TOTAL3
     FROM
         SET1

     UNION ALL

     SELECT
          DATE,
          TOTAL1,
          TOTAL2,
          TOTAL3
     FROM
         SET2
) SubQueryAlias
GROUP BY
     DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you want a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(T1.DATE,T2.DATE) AS DATE,
        COALESCE(T1.TOTAL1,0)+COALESCE(T2.TOTAL1,0) AS TOTAL1,
        COALESCE(T1.TOTAL2,0)+COALESCE(T2.TOTAL2,0) AS TOTAL2,
        COALESCE(T1.TOTAL3,0)+COALESCE(T2.TOTAL3,0) AS TOTAL3
FROM Table1 T1
FULL JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.DATE = T2.DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You still want to do a join but name the columns explicitly, something like this.

```
SELECT Date, T1.Total1 + T2.Total1 AS TOTAL1, ...
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.Date = T2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL to create 1 table of both sets.
Then GROUP BY date and SUM up all totals.

```
create table set1 (
 d date,
 total1 number,
 total2 number,
 total3 number
);

create table set2 (
 d date,
 total1 number,
 total2 number,
 total3 number
);

insert into set1 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('01.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0,0,5);
insert into set1 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('02.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0,0,12);
insert into set1 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('03.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0,0,34);
insert into set1 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('04.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0,0,50);

insert into set2 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('01.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1,2,0);
insert into set2 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('02.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4,12,0);
insert into set2 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('03.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 5,12,0);
insert into set2 (d, total1, total2, total3) values (to_date('04.06.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 6,10,0);

commit;

select d, sum(total1) as total1, sum(total2) as total2, sum(total3) as total3 from (
  select d, total1, total2, total3 from set1
  union all
  select d, total1, total2, total3 from set2
) group by d
order by d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar:

```
INSERT INTO set3 (date,Total1,Total2,Total3)
    SELECT s1.date
       ,case when s1.date=s2.date then s1.Total1+s2.Total1 end as Total1
       ,case when s1.date=s2.date then s1.Total2+s2.Total2 end as Total2
       ,case when s1.date=s2.date then s1.Total3+s2.Total3 end as Total3
    FROM set1 s1, set2 s2
    WHERE s1.date=s2.date
```

It works only when you want to add columns with same date. It will not handle rows where the date is different...